# How to merge array

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays like

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array2
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
i want make 
Array3 Like
(
    [0] => ([0]=>1 [1]=>a)
    [1] => ([0]=>2 [1]=>b)
    [2] => ([0]=>3 [1]=>c)
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: This question was answered pretty often on SO, please use the search first…

Comment: Also you would have to make sure that both arrays have the same length. Or decide on a rule what to do when they're not.

Comment: i know the merge function but i dont want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SPL's [MultipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php)

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr1));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr2));
$result = array();
foreach($mi as $details) {
    $result[] = $details;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not the prettiest way to do it, but since you haven't supplied any attempted code, I doubt anybody wants to bother with this question so here:

**NOTE:** As stated in the comments, you're going to have to make sure the two arrays are the same length and sort that out yourself.

```
$one = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3'
);

$two = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
);

$derp = array();

foreach($one as $key => $val) {
    $derp[] = array(
        $val,
        $two[$key]
    );
}
?>
```

Which returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => c
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks for this help,it is solved